# Problem when returning values from Java ResultSet

Tags: java, set, resultset

For some reason I am only returning 1 entry but I have 2 pending users.

```
public Set getApplicationStatus() {
        DbConn connector = new DbConn();
        String Pending = "Pending";
        Connection connection = connector.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `Department` = '"+Pending+"'");
            Set persons = new HashSet();            
            while (rs.next()) {
                Person person = extractUserFromResultSet(rs);
                persons.add(person);   
            }
            System.out.println(persons.size());
            return persons;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

If I run the query direct on the database I get both accounts but if I go through the `ResultSet` I seem to be only getting the last one.

[image]

[image]

```
public static Person p = new Person();
public static ArrayList<Person> Users = new ArrayList();

public boolean WriteTOfile() throws IOException {

    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("Output.json")) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Users = p.getApplicationStatus();

        for (Person User : Users) {

            String json = gson.toJson(User);
            writer.write(json);
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

When I'm writing to my Json file it adds the last row twice?

```
 public ArrayList<Person> getApplicationStatus() {
    DbConn connector = new DbConn();
    String Pending = "Pending";
    Connection connection = connector.getConnection();
    try {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `Department` = '"+Pending+"'");
        ArrayList persons = new ArrayList();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Person person = extractUserFromResultSet(rs);
            persons.add(person);   
        }
        //System.out.println("Persons Size: " + persons.size());
        return persons;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

First Problem Solved with this code

[image]

```
 public ArrayList<Person> getApplicationStatus() {
    DbConn connector = new DbConn();
    String Pending = "Pending";
    Connection connection = connector.getConnection();
    try {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `Department` = '"+Pending+"'");
        ArrayList persons = new ArrayList();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Person person = extractUserFromResultSet(rs);
            persons.add(person); 
            System.out.println(person);
        }
        //System.out.println("Persons Size: " + persons.size());
        return persons;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

First return printn

```
public boolean WriteTOfile() throws IOException {

    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("Output.json")) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Users = p.getApplicationStatus();

        for (Person User : Users) {

            String json = gson.toJson(User);
            System.out.println(json);
            writer.write(json);
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Second Return printn

[image]

```
 private Person extractUserFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    person.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
    person.setFName(rs.getString("FName"));
    person.setLName(rs.getString("LName"));
    person.setDOB(rs.getString("DOB"));
    person.setDepartment(rs.getString("Department"));
    person.setLocation(rs.getString("Location"));
    person.setCellNr(rs.getString("Cellnr"));
    person.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
    person.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));

    return person;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could they both be `equal()` to each other and return the same `hashCode()`? If so, the Set will ignore the duplicate.

Comment: I'm "guessing" that the `hashCode`/`equals` implementation of `Person` is returning the same value for both rows, thus the `HashSet` is ignoring the second result.  Try using a `List` (ie `ArrayList`) instead

Comment: hmmm makes sense. Thanks ill give it a try.

Comment: Now it gets 2 but it returns the last row twice.

Comment: Have you sorted out your first issue. If so how? Because you could be adding the last row twice.  As i don't see any issue with your write function.

Comment: solved with instead of using a Set and Hash, I used ArrayList.. Thats all I changed.

Comment: Hmm. From the code i see no reason for it to do that other than. There is a duplicate row in the database. Add a println in the rs.next loop and the loop for writing. Lets see where the extra addition is happening. So we know which loop is having a bad day.

Comment: Okay, I added the print lines. Also added the database rows that needs to return.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for late reply. So i believe the problem lies one this method `extractUserFromResultSet` please post the implementation for it. Do a quick test. Add another pending user and i believe you will have 3 duplicate of the last person.

Comment: Yes, were you correct, it duplicates the person 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure where you declared person that is in the extract method.

But declaring one locally in the method should fix the problem fingers crossed.

So i think whats happening is you declared a global person. And you are setting the fields on that. So there is one person object and you are just changing its details. When you add it to the arraylist your add the reference to the same person. So in the end you have added 3 references to the same person object. That person object has had his fields set to the last entry in db. I hope it makes sense.

The reason i come to this conclusion is the println i got you to do in the rs.next loop when you print the person its printing the same reference. Once you make the change below you will see that the references change. Because you create a new person each time and return that new person object and then a reference to that is added to the arraylist.

```
private Person extractUserFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException { 

    // add this line below
    Person person = new Person();

    person.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
    person.setFName(rs.getString("FName")); 
    person.setLName(rs.getString("LName")); 
    person.setDOB(rs.getString("DOB")); 
    person.setDepartment(rs.getString("Department")); 
    person.setLocation(rs.getString("Location")); 
    person.setCellNr(rs.getString("Cellnr")); 
    person.setUsername(rs.getString("Username")); 
    person.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
    return person;
}
```

Comment: No worries, Glad you got it fixed. I hope you also learnt some ways to also debug.